# neo4j LOAD CSV returns Couldn't Load external resource

Tags: csv, neo4j

Trying CSV import to Neo4j - doesn't seem to be working.

I'm loading a local file using the syntax:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///location/local/my.csv" AS csvDoc
```

Am wondering if there's something wrong with my CSV file, or if there's some syntax problem here.

If you didn't read the title, the error is:

```
Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/location/local/my.csv
[Neo.TransientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailure]
```

Answer (score 2):

Neo4j seems to need a full path spec to get a file on the local system.

On **linux** or **mac** try

> LOAD CSV FROM `"file:/Users/you/location/local/my.csv"`

On **windows** try

> LOAD CSV FROM `"file://c:/location/local/my.csv"`

.

Answer (score 0):

In the browser interface (Neo4j 3.0.3, MacOS 10.11) it looks like Neo4j prefixes your file path with $path_to_graph_database/import. So you could move your files there. If you are using a command line tool, then see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149712/load-csv-fails-in-cypher-neo4j-loadexternalresourceexception-couldnt-load-t).

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution:
Once you choose your database location (in my case ReactomeGraphDB60)...
[here I placed my ddbb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI40t.jpg)
...go to that folder, and create inside a folder called "import".

Later in the cypher query write (as an example):
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///ILClasiffStruct.csv" AS row
CREATE (n:Interleukines)
SET n = row