# Neo4j load csv error : Couldn't load the external resource

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j3.0.1 and for loading a csv file

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///D:/dummy.csv' as line
CREATE (:myData {line})
```

But it throws an error :

> Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/D:/dummy.csv

Note : I've already tried configuring **neo4j.conf** which was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444448/neo4j-load-csv-returns-couldnt-load-external-resource-neo4j-lost-in-directory/37444571#37444571)

Suggest any other alternative besides placing csv file into **import** folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting [dbms.directories.import](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.directories.import) to `D:` in `neoj4.conf`

```
dbms.directories.import=D:
```

and after run

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///dummy.csv' as line
CREATE (:myData {line})
```

**EDIT:**

As shown in comments the problem was solved by changing the owner of the CSV file location directory, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29027450/6835358).

```
sudo chown neo4j:adm <csv file location>
```

Comment: thanks, worked around user permissions a bit and it worked !